# How can I replace "and" with another conjunction? I write in Spanish

Tags: apacite

How can I change 'and' in my cites? E.g. "Rojas and Torres" -- I want "Rojas y Torres".

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` in your peamble.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you use biblatex or bibtex? If it's the latter, which bibliography style do you employ.

Comment: If you are indeed using `biblatex` as you tag suggests, you should automatically get Spanish localisation strings if you write in Spanish (and tell LaTeX about that with `babel` or `piolyglossia`). For other packages and styles more work will be required. Please tell us which bibliography and citation packages you use and which style in an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) or MWEB (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Without that info we can't really help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: Any news here? Unfortunately, your question is lacking important details and therefore can't really be answered properly at the moment. All attempts to help you would have to resort to wild guessing and might send you on a wild goose chase or be counterproductive. If the question is not clarified with more information about the packages you use (and ideally an MWE) I will vote to close this question as *unclear what you are asking*.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm using:

**\usepackage[spanish]{babel} **. solution, thanks for your help.

**\usepackage{apacite}** % I'don't know if is this what are you talking about.

At the end I put:

**\bibliographystyle{apalike}**

**\bibliography{biblio}**. In this moment I continue without the

Comment: If you are using `\usepackage{apacite}` (i.e. apa**cite**) you probably also want to use `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and not apa**like**. `apacite` has a Spanish localisation and should be able to say 'y'. `apalike` on the other hand is English only. (Of course the two styles also differ in many other respects: `apalike` is basically just author-year citation with nothing fancy going on, while `apacite` tries to implement the complex rules of the Publication Manual of the APA.) I didn't investigate further for a lack of a poper MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864